# Inverse Fourier transform of $\frac{\sin(a\omega)}{(\omega-a)^2}^2$.

Tags: fourier-transform

The exercise asks that we find the IFT of 
$$\frac{\sin(a\omega)}{(\omega-a)^2}^2$$

Using the general formula for IFT yields integrals of the type: 
$$\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\cos(a\omega)}{(\omega-a)^2}$$ which has no apparent solution (at the known integrals tables i checked).

I suspect some of FT's properties can be of use (multiplication on frequency domain  = convolution in time domain) but since i cant find a function whose FT is in terms of $\sin(a\omega)$ or $(\omega-a)^2$ I can't figure it out.

Comment: The code for $-\infty$ is just -\infty :)

Comment: @GregMartin It doesn't display correctly (i copy pasted -\infty in the place of \infty)

Comment: I've already edited it. The "trick" is to use curly brackets to enclose all that you want as a subscript. (The same aplies for superscripts, numerators, denominators, etc.)

Comment: What is the FT of $e^{-a|t|}$ ? So what is the FT of $\frac{1}{(\omega-a)^2}$ ? So what is the FT of $\frac{e^{i b \omega}}{(\omega-a)^2}$ and $\frac{\sin(a \omega)^2}{(\omega-a)^2}$ ?

Comment: @reuns i believe FT of $e^{-a|t|}$ is $\frac{2j\omega}{a^2-\omega^2}$

Comment: You meant $\frac{2i a}{a^2+\omega^2}$, assuming $a \in \mathbb{C}, Re(a) > 0$

Comment: Yes, my bad. (without the $i$ on the numerator that is)